# I am trying to write a function that returns the number of vowels in a string

Tags: javascript

This is my code but I am getting undefined in the console

```js
function numOfVowels(string) {
      let count = 0;
    
      string = string.split('');
    
      const vowels = function(string) {
        for (let i = 0; i > string.length; i++) {
          if (string[i].toLowerCase() === 'a' || string[i].toLowerCase() === 'e' || string[i].toLowerCase() === 'i' || string[i].toLowerCase() === 'o' || string[i].toLowerCase() === 'u'){
            count+= 1;
          }
          return count;
        }
      };
    }
    console.log(numOfVowels('Yellow Submarine'));
```

Comment: Also, what's undefined? Have you debugged it?

Comment: You're never returning from `numOfVowels`.

Comment: I believe ``Yellow Submarine`` is coming back undefined or the ``count'``. -- it is the count i just double checked

Comment: You do realize that if you call `vowels` it will return on its first iteration?

Comment: @JamesClarke You're never returning from `numOfVowels`, and you're never calling `vowels`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning a value from numOfVowels, and there's also no need to split the string, you can iterate over it, take a look at the code below:

```js
function numOfVowels(string) {
      let count = 0;
    
      for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (string[i].toLowerCase() === 'a' || string[i].toLowerCase() === 'e' || string[i].toLowerCase() === 'i' || string[i].toLowerCase() === 'o' || string[i].toLowerCase() === 'u'){
          count+= 1;
        }
      }
      
      return count;
}

console.log(numOfVowels('Yellow Submarine'));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues here:

1. You declare but don't call the function `vowels`.
2. Your return statement `return count;` in inside of your loop and will return on the first iteration.
3. Your conditional in the `for` loop is using `>` and it should use `<` otherwise your code block inside the `for` loop would never run as `i` would never be greater than `string.length`.

A few alternative implementations of vowel counting using regex & es2015:

```js
var s = "Yellow Submarine";

// es2015/es6
// using reduce
let count1 = s.split('').reduce( (count,char) => ( /[aeiou]/i.test(char) ) ? count + 1 : count, 0);

// using filter
let count2 = s.split('').filter( char => /[aeiou]/i.test(char) ).length;

console.log(count1);
console.log(count2);
```

Comment: There won't be a type error, the loop just runs once. Other than that very good and comprehensive answer!

Comment: @Christoph right, I meant if #2 was fixed. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: There will be no error. The condition is not satisfied, thus the code block will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a bit shorter implementation ( just sayin ):

```
countvowels=word=>word.split("").reduce((c,l)=>(["a","e","i","o","u"].indexOf(l.toLowerCase())+1)?++c:c,0);
```

http://jsbin.com/durizarobu/edit?console

Answer (score 0):

Here is corrected code

first problem was with `i > string.length` it should be `i < string.length` in `for` loop second problem was with `return count;` it should be after the loop gets completed and the third problem was with `vowels` function it was never being called inside `numOfVowels`.

```
function numOfVowels(string) {

  let count = 0;

  string = string.split('');

  const vowels = function(string) {

    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
      if (string[i].toLowerCase() === 'a' || string[i].toLowerCase() === 'e' || string[i].toLowerCase() === 'i' || string[i].toLowerCase() === 'o' || string[i].toLowerCase() === 'u'){
        count+= 1;
      }
    }
      return count;
  };
  return vowels(string);
}

console.log(numOfVowels('Yellow Submarine'));
```